# Unable to connect to the internet via web browser

Tags: networking, web-browsers

I use raspberry pi model b+

I'm able to update and install software using command line, but I'm unable to access internet through web browser.
The message says

```
Could not connect: Network is unreachable
```

I'm unable to even find the settings page to connect to a http/https proxy (I use a proxy).
Where can I find the settings?

Comment: WRT settings, you should indicate *which* web browser you are referring to as there are a number of them available, and you have not even indicated what OS you are using, although I *think* the default on Raspbian is `epiphany` (but a I may be wrong and in any case, I am sure you can easily find "Help -> About" or whatever).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried WICD? I believe it allows proxies. Assuming you are using Raspbian, use `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install wicd`.
I hope this helps!